# Postgres Multiple select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `v_xml_cdr` and have a the following columns: `uuid`, `start_epoch` and `end_epoch`. I want to be able to query the table for the `start_epoch` of of a `uuid` and then take that `uuid` and query the table again for all calls that have a `start_epoch` of less than or equal to the `start_epoch` from the previously found `uuid` and an `end_epoch` of greater than or equal to that same previously found `start_epoch`. Here is what I have so far, but it returns an empty result set. It should return 5 rows.

```
select count(uuid)
from v_xml_cdr
where start_epoch
      <= (select start_epoch as reject_start
          from v_xml_cdr
          where uuid = '5c076428-3790-11e7-868a-xxxxx'
         )
  and end_epoch
      >= (select start_epoch as reject_start
          from v_xml_cdr
          where uuid = '5c076428-3790-11e7-868a-xxxxx'
         );
```

Comment: Your query looks fine, except that you run the same subselect twice (maybe try `WHERE (SELECT ...) BETWEEN start_epoch AND end_epoch`). Can you provide sample data to prove that the query does not do what you want? Can you verify that the subselect returns a single row and not NULL?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting the following "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
select count(uuid)
from v_xml_cdr xc join
     (select min(start_epoch) as minse
      from v_xml_cdr xc1
      where uuid = '5c076428-3790-11e7-868a-xxxxx'
     ) xc1
     on xc.start_epoch <= xc1.minse and
        xc.end_epoch >= xc1.minse;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you so much. This solved my problem. Just 1 further question, is there any way to only list if count(uuid) is greater than 5?

Comment: append to the query: `having count(uuid) > 5`

Comment: @user3896519 . . . I'm not sure what that means.  This returns only one column and one row.  What should it return if the count is not greater than 5?